# How do I get my VS Code terminal to call variables without getting an error?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I cannot get my VS Code terminal to communicate properly with the file editor window. Every time I call a variable, which I have defined, I get a traceback error saying that it the variable is not defined. This is what I am trying to reference, I have made sure to save the file (many times), as well as make sure everything is being interpreted as python code in the terminal.

`greeting = "hello, Python"`

This is the error that comes back when I try to call the variable (I just used print as an example):

```
>>> print(greeting)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'greeting' is not defined
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! (this is my first time using python in VS code, I have only used VS code for html so this is new to me!)

Comment: The terminal does not know about your python file. The terminal in VS Code is just a normal command line. You can execute your python file from there. But you cannot refer to stuff from the python file.  Your variable is not defined until the python file is executed.
If you are new to VS Code do not bother with the terminal. Just write and run python files. You can put the print(greeting) into the python file.

Comment: The error says that the `print()` statement is on line 1, so there is no previous line of code where you defined `greeting`.  You need to put `greeting = "..."` in _the same code file_ as the `print()` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to put the print line before the variable, it’ll return that error.  It will also do that if you try print(greeting) as a stand-alone execution.  Try:

```py
greeting = "Hello, Python!"
print(greeting)
```

Answer (score 0):

Terminals and scripts are different. If you are in a shell terminal then you can execute commands like `py name.py` to run scripts.

[image]

If you are in a python interactive terminal, then you can type and run python code directly. For example the following

[image]

If you are just starting to use python in VS code, it is helpful to read the [starting documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial). Install the [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension and use `Run Python File` to execute the script. This eliminates the need for you to manually type the command

[image]

Use the shortcut `Shift+Enter` to open an interactive terminal and execute the selected code, also without you having to manually type the code.